# multiple led driver in serie on a single slave

Tags: spi, led-driver

I expect to build a module that could be cloned and linked in serie. 
I d like to workaround a led driver ( [MAX6969ANG+](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2002194.pdf) ) to pilot a photo coupler to pilot a triac to pilot a 60VAC output with arduino using SPI.

My question : Is two or more IC can be serialized on a single slave letting me have 0-16/17-32/33-48/49-64/etc addressable photocoupler ?

Regards

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you add some schematic to your question?

Comment: I want to chain multiple Led driver on the same SPI slave with common GND, CLK, V+ and chained DOUT of the first to the DIN of the second and so on. I just want to know if it s a good practice.

Each modules that I plan to do is a circuit with a LED Driver that can be extends with an another module like this http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-SPI-7-Bi-color-LED-Matrix-Scrolling-Text-D/step2/Wiring/. Nevermind about triac and optocoupler :)

Comment: That's kinda what the DOUT pin is for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are asking about daisy chaining.
This is block diagram of MAX6969 (datasheet, page 6):
[image]

As you can see, there is serial-to-parallel shift register, which outputs to DOUT. So, yes, you can daisy chain multiple MAX6969 chips.

Comment: just one more question is there a limit of chaining ? and distance limit between the modules if need to wired them ?

Comment: @S7th try to read datasheet. All limits should be written there.

Comment: Sorry for the unexciting question but i'm little bit lost in all the diagrams and datas maybe you could enlighten me as we were on  a mutual aid and sharing forum ?

Comment: @S7th it's right at the beginning of the datasheet. It's capable of 25Mb/s. SPI is not suitable for long distances, it's just a local bus. If you want to transmit for long distances, use something like RS485.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not sure of what 25Mb/s represents in term of limit but i will deal with it. :)